# Installing opencv3 on mac with home-brew

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, opencv3.0

I've been trying a few things in installing opencv3 for osx. I need it for python 3 (currently using anaconda).

I tried the following:

```
localhost:~ nicolas$ brew install opencv3
Warning: You are using OS X 10.8.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
==> Installing opencv3 from homebrew/science
==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/science/opencv3: homebrew/python/numpy
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv3 dependency: homebrew/python/numpy
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/4c/515d7c4ac424ff38cc919f
Already downloaded: /Users/nicolas/Library/Caches/Homebrew/numpy-1.11.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nose/nose-1.3.7.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/nicolas/Library/Caches/Homebrew/numpy--nose-1.3.7.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/
==> python setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95 --parallel=1 install --prefix=/usr/local
==> python -c import numpy; assert numpy.test().wasSuccessful()
Last 15 lines from /Users/nicolas/Library/Logs/Homebrew/numpy/03.python:
TypeError: 'buffer' does not have the buffer interface

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5757 tests in 65.851s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=6, SKIP=11, errors=1)
Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.11.1
NumPy relaxed strides checking option: False
NumPy is installed in /usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.11.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
Python version 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]
nose version 1.3.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew):
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues

These open issues may also help:
Numpy HEAD builds require cython https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/330
Warning: You are using OS X 10.8.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

1. First of all I'm unsure what this means. Is it a success or a fail? When I start python I can't import cv2 so I assume it didn't work correctly. How can I find out more about the reason for the failure?
2. Why is there a reference to python 2? My standard python is currently python 3 (which is started when I type in 'python').

Comment: First: It says that homebrew does not support 10.8. Why don't you upgrade your OS? Second: try `brew install opencv3 --with-python3`

Comment: Can't upgrade because my hackintosh won't work anymore if I upgrade the OS. Thanks for the advice.